# CVS_RSH for git

Tags: git, ssh

I want to specify the path to the openssh binary for git. For CVS you can do this with

```
CVS_RSH="~/openssh/bin/ssh"
```

in your dotfiles. Is there an equivalent for git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'GIT_SSH'. See [git(1)](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git.html) for the documentation.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking in the many git.config options. I thought git had moved beyond environment variables to configure things.

Answer (score 1):

The GIT_SSH answer may be what you're looking for, but note that for finer control over connections you can specify a core.gitproxy executable instead.  This will take two arguments specifying host and port and can be used to make arbitrarily complicated connections (e.g. through a proxy, or ssh tunnel, etc...) based on the host you are trying to pull from.